# setting wcf endpoint headers in code

Tags: wcf, header

What is the **code equivalent** of setting endpoint headers in configuration?

```
<client>
<endpoint address="http://localhost/..." >
<headers>
<something>blah</something>
</headers>
</endpoint>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
var header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("something", "", "blah");

using (new OperationContextScope(channel))
{
  OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);

  //your normal call here
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to assign these beforehand to the client or channelfactory without having to be in the current operation context?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative that doesn't require creating a new OperationContextScope and setting the header every time you use the client is to specify the headers when creating the [EndpointAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.endpointaddress.aspx).

Example (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5340009/35233)

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding ();
var address = new EndpointAddress (
    new Uri (RemoteAddress),
    new AddressHeader[] {
        AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader ("APIKey", "", "bda11d91-7ade-4da1-855d-24adfe39d174")
    });

var client = new ExampleClient (binding, address);
```