# How add cutom header in WCF with dynamic user values to every call?

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I am consuming one java webservice with WCF client.
I want to pass user related information to service in header. **I have aleady gone to through thread
[How to add a custom header to every WCF calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-header-to-every-wcf-calls)**

I have implemented `IClientMessageInspector` interface with `BeforeSendRequest`() method. Now, I want to pass user related information in SOAP header like Oraganization, which may differ for every user. I have all this information in my ASP.net application, which uses this service.

Is there anyway I can pass user related information to this `BeforeSendRequest`() method from asp.net session and build Message header before sending any request?

Answer (score 1):

There are few options

1. Put the information in `Session` and retrieve it in `BeforeSendRequest`
2. Put it in `HttpContext.Current.Items` and retrieve it in `BeforeSendRequest'
3. Use Thread Local Storage (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sby1byh.aspx)

Comment: Thread local storage is anti pattern in ASP.NET because threads are reused for many requests.

Comment: @Ladislav: I did not know this. Thanks for the information. Even then, a request would be only on one thread, right? So in this particular example, I can still use TLS. Isn't it?