# How do I attach a SOAP Header to my C# client?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, soapheader

I have my web service set up to recieve a soap header of name `"TestHeader"` with param `"Name"`

**How do i create a soap header in my client AND send it to the service?**

So far I have created it in my client.

```
public class TestHeader : SoapHeader
{
    public String Name;
}
```

Initialised my service,

```
    Test.TestServicesClient SOAP = new Test.TestServicesClient();
```

Initialised my header.

```
  TestHeader header = new TestHeader();
```

set variable in header

```
header.Name = "BoB";
```

Now what? Ive tried following MSDN, and other tutorials but not got anywhere.

**TestService.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace Test
{

    // Define a SOAP header by deriving from the SoapHeader class.
    public class TestHeader : SoapHeader
    {
        public String Name;
    }

   public class TestService : ITestServices
    {      

        public TestHeader TestInHeader;


       [WebMethod]
        [SoapHeader("TestInHeader", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In)]
        public List<ServiceDetails> GetServiceDetails(Int32 CostCentreNo, Int32 ServiceCode, Boolean Recurring)
        {
            throw new System.Exception(TestInHeader.ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the information you provide is not detailed enough only some general pointers:

- [How to add a custom HTTP header to every WCF call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-header-to-every-wcf-calls/1408177#1408177)
- [SoapHeader Class (System.Web.Services.Protocols) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.protocols.soapheader?view=netframework-4.8)

The above links contains solutions including sample code for WCF (first link) and SOAP (second link)...

**EDIT - as per comments:**

[This article (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20200116195245/http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Using-SOAP-Headers-with-ASP-NET-2-0-Web-Services.id-291722.html) gives you a complete walkthrough on implementing custom SOAP headers and setting them before calling the respective service.

Bascially you need to extend the `Test.TestServicesClient` class with the `TestHeader` you defined and then you can just set its value before calling a method of the web service.

Comment: following link 2, can you provide example code on how to connect to it in C# (i.e. creating and sending the soap header)

Comment: see my EDIT above - it contains a link to a complete walktrhough with source etc.

Comment: Since `Test.TestServicesClient` class is initialised as `WCF`, and `TestHeader` as `header`, it should be `WCF.TestHeader = header` or something? I cant seem to either initialise the proxy, (unless I already have, i.e. WCF) or find this option to set the header.

Comment: you don't provide enough information... are you using WCF or are you using some generic SOAP implementation ?

Comment: Generic Soap. It is merely called WCF because in the distant future it is suppose to support both. Sorry, it is confusing. I am merely using SOAP atm. Treat my service as the same as link 2. I just need to send this header to it.

Comment: ok - please show the declaration of your client class or just add `TestHeader` as a public property to `Test.TestServicesClient`...

Comment: that sounds like it would do the trick. But how do I do that :O

Comment: to create an example: please edit your question and show the declaration of `Test.TestServicesClien`...

Comment: This problem is so frustrating, taken me all day :( And i bet it seomthing simple, but i cant see what

Comment: you put the server side class into the question... but your question was about extending your `TestServicesClient` to send a custom header... now I am really confused... what is your goal exactly ?

Comment: Aye, I was hoping that an example of how to send a soap header to my service as shown, could be provided :). My client code is the above in bits, but is incomplete anyway (as it doesnt work).

Answer (score 5):

I guess I'm a little late, but here's the answer:

```
    Test.TestHeader header = new Test.TestHeader();
    header.Name = "BoB";
    Test.TestService SOAP = new Test.TestService();
    SOAP.TestHeaderValue = header;
    SOAP.GetServiceDetails(0,0,False);
```

Here's a [LINK](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27365/Authenticate-NET-Web-Service-with-Custom-SOAP-Head) that clarifies the subject:
"...Visual Studio will create a property in web service proxy called 'UserCredentialsValue' which will map the 'consumer' public property [which inherits from SoapHeader] in the web service."