# How to set WCF service to check SOAP Header

Tags: c#, wcf

I had a .asmx web service that check parameters of soap header like this:

```
    public class Credential : SoapHeader
    {
        public string username;
        public string password;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [SoapHeader("ClientCredential")]
    public BE78[] Get78(BE78Equal equal, ref ResponseInfo info)
```

now, i want to re-implement something like this with WCF service. How can I do that without adding ClientCredential as input parameter of the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good explanation of how to achieve what you ask for: [How to add a custom HTTP header to every WCF call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-header-to-every-wcf-calls)