# Add custom header in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, http-headers, soapheader

I have the following examplecode in Java:

```
PushServiceService c = new PushServiceService();
service = c.getPushServicePort();
BindingProvider ccBindingProvider = (BindingProvider) service;
Map ccRequestContext = ccBindingProvider.getRequestContext();
ccRequestContext.put(BindingProvider.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY, true);
Map ccRequestHeaders = new HashMap(); // is actually a Map for String to List of Strings
ccRequestHeaders.put("Cookie", Arrays.asList("JSESSIONID=ABC123"));
ccRequestContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, ccRequestHeaders);
```

I'm trying to accomplish the same using C# code, but don't understand all of it.

It is especially the lines

```
ccRequestContext.put(BindingProvider.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY, true);
```

and

```
ccRequestHeaders.put("Cookie", Arrays.asList("JSESSIONID=ABC123"));
```

that I have trouble understanding. From what I can understand they either add an HTTP header or a SOAP header.

Any ideas on how to do the same using C#?

Answer (score 1):

see 
[how-to-add-a-custom-header-to-every-wcf-calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1408177/262900)