# Authentifcation using GUID + Windows 8

Tags: c#, wcf, microsoft-metro

When I add a service reference to my MVC3 application: I obtain methods which take a `guid` in parameter:

```
void getcities( string token);
void getCountry( string token);
```

but when I add a service reference to a Windows 8 application, the proxy generated doesn't include a token:

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Maquette_MyAirport_Win8.ServiceFlightInfo.CitiesResponse> GetAllCitiesAsync() 
{
  Maquette_MyAirport_Win8.ServiceFlightInfo.BaseRequest inValue = new Maquette_MyAirport_Win8.ServiceFlightInfo.BaseRequest();

  return ((Maquette_MyAirport_Win8.ServiceFlightInfo.FlightInfoService)(this)).GetAllCitiesAsync(inValue);
}
```

So when I call this method without a `guid`, it throws an error: you are not authorized to access this service.

Do you have any solution, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is that the [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute] is not supported in windows 8.

So i add a custom behavior like this to inject headermessage:
[How to add a custom HTTP header to every WCF call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-header-to-every-wcf-calls)