# Returning big byte arrays from WCF - Memory issue

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, memory, large-object-heap

I need to return a big byte array from a WCF server.

The problem is - in order to return such an array - I need to create one - and when creating such an array - it automatically goes to the Large Object Heap - meaning that when the service is stressed - I'm getting a real problem in memory usage and management.

I thought about using unmanaged memory to avoid using large managed byte arrays - but still - how can I return such an array from a WCF service?

Is there any way of returning a "Stream" of bytes from a WCF service that does not include actually creating a managed byte array? I know that WCF itself uses a BufferManager - so if it just reads my unmanaged memory and uses its buffer management to store it before sending - I hopefully won't have a problem.

Comment: Can you try to write it to a file and let the clients download the file?

Comment: Yes you can return `Stream`. Why don't you try.

Comment: ryadavilli - I'm afraid that writing and reading from a file is 1. not secure in some cases (when the data is sensitive) and 2. requires IO which is bad in terms of performance

Comment: L.B - Returning an UnmanagedMemoryStream is impossible - In order to return a MemoryStream - it has to be backed by a byte array...

Comment: @RoyReznik FileStream is also stream :) You can also implement your own stream which doesn't load all the data into the memory at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WCF's [Streaming Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx). From that page:

> 1. To stream data, the OperationContract for the service must satisfy two requirements:
>
>    a.  The parameter that holds the data to be streamed must be the only
>      parameter in the method. For example, if the input message is the one
>      to be streamed, the operation must have exactly one input parameter.
>      Similarly, if the output message is to be streamed, the operation must
>      have either exactly one output parameter or a return value.
>
>    b.  At least one of the types of the parameter and return value must be
>      either [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx), [Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.aspx), or [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx).
> 2. Streaming must be enabled on the binding. You set a TransferMode property, which can take one of the following values:
>
>    a. Buffered,
>
>    b. Streamed, which enables streaming communication in both directions.
>
>    c. StreamedRequest, which enables streaming the request only.
>
>    d. StreamedResponse, which enables streaming the response only.

There are some decent examples on that page as well, including how to write back a custom stream (it's toward the bottom).

For more background info on encoding, streaming and sessions, and some security considerations when using streaming, see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx).

Comment: Sounds very promising - I'll check it out.

Comment: Unfortunately, after checking the restrictions - my method also returns 2 additional output parameters (that are a must...) - Any way to bypass that?

Comment: You can try passing the parameters in the message header by using the OperationContext.OutgoingMessageHeaders Property. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.outgoingmessageheaders.aspx: "Use this property to add reply headers that are sent by a service operation or request headers that are sent by a WCF client object."
There are some pretty good examples of that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-header-to-every-wcf-calls/

Comment: Found a much simpler way - Just create a class that has the MessageContract attribute - all parameters (that are not streamed) should have the MessageHeader attribute and the streamed parameter should have the  MessageBodyMember attribute