# How to add the SOAP header to all the methods in WCFSTORM tool

Tags: wcf, testing

I am trying to add the message header to all the methods in the WCFStorm , There is a concept of adding soap header to each method manually. But I couldn't find the way to add the SOAP header to all the methods automatically. Can someone guide me.

Thanks in Advance,
Sudhakar Byna.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-header-to-every-wcf-call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a custom HTTP header to every WCF call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-http-header-to-every-wcf-call)