# How to compress WCF 3.5 response & use WCF service in WPF application

Tags: wpf, wcf

I want to send compress data from WCF 3.5 service as a response & access that responce in WPF application.
     I have hosted WCF application on IIS & implemented IIS Compression to send compress response to client.
I have implemented iis compression by referring following link

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingDynamicCompressionGzipDeflateForWCFDataFeedsODataAndOtherCustomServicesInIIS7.aspx

> Compression work properly when I access that WCF service in MVC
>   application. But when I try to access same WCF service in WPF
>   application Fiddler showing that service response is not compressed.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you please provide relevant part of your web.config & app.config. In addition what is the difference in the headers sent to the server in both cases (MVC vs. WPF)?

Comment: In both MVC & WPF application we have added following binding setting in config file

Comment: In both MVC & WPF(Windows) application we have added following binding setting in config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both MVC & WPF(Windows) application we have added following binding setting in config file

```
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding  name="EndPointHTTP" closeTimeout="00:59:00" openTimeout="00:59:00" receiveTimeout="00:59:00" sendTimeout="00:59:00"
                 allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">

          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

<client>
      <endpoint address="http://ntvmsynrpt0389/SynergyLiteServicetInternet/SystemAdmin/SystemAdminService.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EndPointHTTP"
          contract="ISystemAdmin" name="SystemAdminServiceEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="CallContextEndpointBehavior">
      </endpoint>
 </client>
```

We got header in MVC as
 Request Header

> POST /SynergyAfricaServices/SystemAdmin/SystemAdminService.svc
>   HTTP/1.1 Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 Host:
>   ntvmsynrpt0389.fps.nihilent.com Content-Length: 4132 Expect:
>   100-continue Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Response Header

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
>   Content-Encoding: gzip Vary: Accept-Encoding Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Wed, 05 Jun 2013 12:44:18 GMT
>   Content-Length: 1179

For WPF application we got fidder output as
Request Header

> POST /SynergyLiteServicetInternet/Common/InfrastructureService.svc
>   HTTP/1.1 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>   VsDebuggerCausalityData:
>   uIDPo93vMvxA6GNCkVCT0f7hH3cAAAAASYZ0KzDZuUqLJNzHwK2nZidcwKk9ROFEsMvZpKu5Rw0ACQAA
>   SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IInfrastructure/LoadMenus" Host:
>   ntvmsynrpt0389 Content-Length: 965 Expect: 100-continue

Response Header

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: private Content-Length: 72001
>   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Fri, 07 Jun
>   2013 06:14:51 GMT

Answer (score 0):

The second set of request headers is missing Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate. Please follow [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-header-to-every-wcf-calls) to inject appropriate header.