# Are there events for WCF method call start and finish?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, events

I am producing a WPF application using a WCF service to feed it data.  Normal boring stuff.  I am not using RIA.

I have a global view model, in which I maintain just one reference to the service client object I use for all service calls.  I have a little screen blocker to stop users from interacting with the application while it waits for important data.  I would like this to be automated across my entire application.  So I am looking for events on the service client (or its inner channel) to hook into so I can automatically do this.

So far I've not found them.  The closest I've got are the completed events of each method exposed by the web service - but nothing for when the methods are called.  I did some WPF/WCF work a few years back and I managed to make this work but I cannot remember how.  Does anyone know the secret?

Comment: Why do you want to block the users from interacting with your application? That's something we've tried to avoid in UI for over a decade.

Comment: This is just an admin tool for internal use within the company.  I'm trying to get it done quickly.  This seemed like a quicker method than remembering to disable buttons here there and everywhere when making the data calls.

Comment: you'd do better by simply ensuring that an extra click on a button doesn't do anything harmful. Then you could focus on a general technique for disabling a clicked button until the entire action is completed. This would be a better, reusable tool than simply disabling the UI when a WCF call is in progress.

Comment: Yeah that would be a better approach, but it would use the same principal as I'm about to outline / mark as answer below.  Rather than blocking the whole UI I can block other stuff with only minor changes to code.  Again I know this isn't ideal, but it is a "AAAAH QUICK!!!" solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class that implements [IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx) and register it by using a behavior. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-header-to-every-wcf-calls) for a great answer.

Comment: Hi Markus! This looks pretty good and not too difficult to put together.  Very flexible too, so I can play with it some more.  I will try implementing it and let you know the result (and mark as answer then).

Comment: The link shared by Markus here led to the solution, and this is a very good walkthrough of what I did (except I didn't need to configure anything on my server).  I notified events on my global view model which then block and show the UI as I had wanted.  John is right in that this isn't a great solution, but instead of blocking UI you could easily code in something more clever if you wanted, like cancelling identical requests to the service when it hasn't returned yet.
http://msmvps.com/blogs/paulomorgado/archive/2007/04/27/wcf-building-an-http-user-agent-message-inspector.aspx

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a proxy of the proxy. The new proxy would basically wrap each call: raise a starting event, call actual method, raise an ending event. With a little help of something that could create such proxy for you, this could be easy. Castle.DynamicProxy should do the trick.

Comment: Hi Wiktor.  This is a very cool project, thanks for sharing.  I am going to try Markus's suggestion below (which is basically the same idea, though a bit more manual).

Comment: No problem. The dynamic proxy approach is much more general in a sense that you could alter the behavior of ANY object, from any subsystem. Markus approach leverages the fact that WCF can be instrumented in its own specific way.