# How to set preemptive authorization type in a c# program

Tags: java, c#, .net, wcf

We are accessing a `java webservice` in .net application which works well in soap UI after setting `preemptive authorization` type.But through c# code when we access the WSDL we are getting some errors.It seems we have to set `preemptive authorization` type in `webconfig` or `c#` code.How to do that?

Comment: Do you mean to add credentials to access the service? When invoking a service using a channel factory, you can add username/password based on authentication.
ChannelFactory<IService1> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://172.17.16.82"));
            factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "administrator";
            factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "123456";

Comment: You may want to take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26437984/2016162

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53838399/error-while-accessing-java-webserivice-in-net   .This is infact the question