# How to add custom request headers to generated Schema.cs with XSD.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, soap, xsd

For a project I'm talking to a SOAP service. This service is using authorization HTTP headers: one static, one dynamic token.

The project is written in C#. I used the XML Schema Definition Tool (XSD.exe) to generate classes from the XSD's. I'm looking for a good way to add the autorization HTTP request headers to the endpoint url (System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress).
I want to keep using the already generated Schema.cs with XSD.exe.

I searched the internet, but I cannot find a solution fast. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Answer (score 1):

You can interecept the operationcontext by writing extention and populate header at runtime using below interfaces

[IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector(v=vs.110).aspx)
[IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Is it only possible to add message headers? I want to add a HTTP header.

Comment: Yes. But service request header.

Comment: Do have an example/link or something like that?

Comment: You need SOAP header not HTTP header. Above mentioned method of implementing interface will work. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-header-to-every-wcf-call/1408177#1408177