# Header behaviour in a virtual MVC application in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, iis

This is my current setup;

In IIS I have two hosted MVC applications, say `App1` is hosted in `app1.mydomain.com`. It has a virtual MVC **application** (not directory) `App2` hosted as `app1.mydomain.com/app2`.

Both applications have a connection to the same WCF service. This WCF service requires headers in their requests and thus I have added behaviours for every call using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-header-to-every-wcf-call).

I have configured both applications' header behaviour correctly (`App1` has `App1MessageHeaderInspector` and `App2` has `App2MessageHeaderInspector`) and have configured both in their own Web.config.

So, `App1` uses;

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://ws.mydomain.com/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWebService" contract="WCFService.IWebService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IWebService" behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceEndpointBehaviour" />
</client>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="App1MessageHeaderInspector" type="App1.App1MessageHeaderBehaviourExtension, App1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null "/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebServiceEndpointBehaviour">
      <App1MessageHeaderInspector />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

And `App2` uses the same configuration, except that `App1MessageheaderInspector` is `App2MessageHeaderInspector`.

I have configured my routing in `App1` to ignore everything going to `/app2`;

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*path}", new { path = @"app2\/(.*)" });
    //...
}
```

And I can succesfully view pages which do not require a connection to the WCF service (i.e. `app1.mydomain.com/app2/Home/Index` returns the correct view).

Now my problem is, as soon as I try to connect to the WCF service with `App2`, I get the following error;

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The type 'App1.App1MessageHeaderBehaviourExtension, App1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null ' registered for extension 'App1MessageHeaderInspector' could not be loaded.

But I don't want `App2` to load the behaviours from `App1`!

I have also tried to encapsulate `<system.web>` with `<location inheritInChildApplications="false">` in `App1`, but without success.

Both applications work as intended when testing from my local PC. There is no Windows authentication or anything like that involved.

I am quite stuck on this topic for a few days now. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration section are inherited/merged by default when a web application is configured under another one like in your case. As you've seen `system.web` section has its mechanism to break inheritance, but this just works for `system.web` and its children (possibly, not even all children).

Having said that, I would give a try at this (in your App2 config):

```
<extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
        <clear />
        <add name="App1MessageHeaderInspector" type="App1.App1MessageHeaderBehaviourExtension, App1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null "/>
    </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the App1.dll in your bin directory under the virtual directory for app2? The message indicates that the dll cannot be found in the usual location (such as /bin)