# Custom binding c# WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I would like to add a security header to my WCF SOAP message that looks like the following:

```
<s:Header>
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">URLWithAction</Action>
<Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
  <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:Username>Username</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>
  </wsse:UsernameToken>
</Security>
</s:Header>
```

Yet, I am unable to figure out if this can be done with basicHttpBinding or another standard one, or if I have to make a custom one and how I can make a custom one...
Is anyone able to help?

Comment: Is this an outgoing or incoming message? Do you want to add the header on the client side or the server side?

Comment: This is an outgoing message from the client

Comment: And the client is C# and using WCF? The answer below is still valid if so. You can use an IClientMessageInspector. I will update my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that I had to play a bit more with the attributes for the security element in my custom binding. I added the tag includeTimestamp="false" and then the security header worked, even though the action element was not added to the header.

Final result of the custombinding was:

```
<customBinding>
 <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_WebService">
  <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8" />
  <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" 
            includeTimestamp="false"/>
  <httpsTransport />
 </binding>
 <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_WebService1"/>
</customBinding>
```

Comment: This saved my day! I've spent a full day trying to make it work. Finally found this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to add the message on either the server or the client side then please look at this answer [How to add a custom HTTP header to every WCF call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-header-to-every-wcf-call)

Comment: Even though it now works with the configuration changes, you are right that this is the correct way of adding custom header tags in WCF.