# Generate SOAP Header to Add services reference generated client/request

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, uwp

I have added a service reference to my `UWP` app project.

I seems everything have been generated correctly, according to the `WSDL`.

The problem is that I don't know how can I add a SOAP header to every message. The reference generated includes a CustomHeader object (a POCO), with all the fields needed according to the request descripcion but I don't know how to either include a soap header and to add this custom header to it, via the generated request (or the generated `ClientBase`).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-header-to-every-wcf-call

Comment: I have tried that already, but in this line `httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER, this.m_userAgent);` it issues an error because it says `Headers` is read only. Thanks anyway!