# WCF - same parameter to all service methods

Tags: c#, wcf

I haven't been working with WCF for ages, now we are developing a Service and its methods receive all the same parameter. Is there a way, that I can pass this parameter throughout a ServiceContext so I don't need to repeat this parameter in every WCF method? My client is a WebApi application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use Headers, here are some links:

http://adilmughal.com/blog/2011/10/client-additional-parameters-using-custom-headers-in-wcf/

[How to add a custom HTTP header to every WCF call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-http-header-to-every-wcf-call)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the additional parameters as OutgoingMessageHeaders in OperationContext which will be accessible in every method.