# Cannot connect to a WCF service with application, but can with SOAPUI

Tags: vb.net, wcf, credentials

I'm trying to consume a WCF service, hosted in a shared server. it works perfectly with SOAPUI, but when i tried to do it with my vb.net application it give me this error:

> the http request is unauthorised with client authentication scheme
>   "anonymous".

I tried a lot of solutions, changing the app.config of my application, adding `security mode="TransportCredentialOnly"`, with `clientCredentialType="Windows"` and `"NTLM"`, and it only changes the last part of the error, giving "Negotiate" with "anonymous".

here how i add security in app.config

```
            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
              <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security>
```

I think this is an application problem because, as I said before, it works perfectly in SOAPUI, I don't know if I need to add something more.

The web.config of WCF:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
              <httpRuntime maxRequestLength ="262144" executionTimeout="103600"/>

    </system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
       <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                          maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                          maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />    

       </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
 </bindings>


    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>

                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
     <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

             <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>
</system.webServer>
```

EDIT:

I just receive an answer from server's provider and he said that there's a program, ModSecurity, that is blocking me access to WCF until i add a correct content header and user agent. How can i add it to the call?

**UPDATE:**

I used the answer of GMan80013 and now i'm stuck in this part.

I'm getting this error "Coul not load type 'Microsoft.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.HttpUserAgentBehaviorExtensionElement, SolutionPruebas.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' registered for the extension 'httpUserAgent'".

This error come from this part, I assume:

```
<behaviorExtensions>

  <add name="httpUserAgent" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.HttpUserAgentBehaviorExtensionElement, SolutionPruebas.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />

</behaviorExtensions>
```

Or from here.

```
    <behaviors>

<endpointBehaviors>

  <behavior name="LegacyServiceEndpointBehavior">

    <httpUserAgent userAgent="test user agent" />

  </behavior>

</endpointBehaviors>
```

Comment: So how is your service configured? It's kinda hard to match two pieces of which you have shown only one...

Comment: Here's my WCF web.config's binding

        
 <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
           <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
               <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                              maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                              maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                              maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />    

           </binding>
       </basicHttpBinding>
     </bindings>

Comment: Please edit your question, comments don't do formating well and are not permanent.

Comment: Sorry for that, edited.

Comment: There does not seem to be any security in your servers bindings, what happens if you remove all security from your client's bindings as well?

Comment: Just tried that, and doesnt work. I added an info about modsecurity in server.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-http-header-to-every-wcf-call) describes how you can modify your client's request headers.