# Skip header validation in BeforeSendRequest

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, .net-core, http-headers

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-http-header-to-every-wcf-call) topic I am using this block of code

```
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request,  System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
{
    HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestMessage;
    object httpRequestMessageObject;
    if (request.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, out httpRequestMessageObject))
    {
        httpRequestMessage = httpRequestMessageObject as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpRequestMessage.Headers[USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER]))
        {
            httpRequestMessage.Headers[USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER] = this.m_userAgent;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        requestMessageProperty.Headers.Add("Authorization",  token);
        request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestMessage);
    }
```

but unfortunately since I move code from .net framwork 4.7 to .net core 2.1 project I am getting this error code:

> Failed to copy the HTTP header 'Authorization' with value
>   'qqqqqqqqq=' to
>   'System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders'.\r\nThe format of value
>   'qqqqqqqqq=' is invalid.

In old project everything worked fine
Is possible to skip Authorization header validation?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

.net core validates Authorization header format.
According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization
the authorization header should be in format:
`Authorization: <type> <credentials>`

You will get this error if your authorization header doesn't contain space between *type* and *credentials* or contains multiple spaces

This will work fine:

```
requestMessageProperty.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"my-custom-auth-type {token}");
```

Comment: I know but target server that i don't control doesn't accept auth type before credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TryAddWithoutValidation` instead of the normal `Add`

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation()
```

or

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
var updateRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PUT"), apiUrl)
updateRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("If-Match", "something);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders.tryaddwithoutvalidation?view=net-8.0