# C# .NET Core SOAP Client basic auth header not set

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, soap, soap-client

I have a client generated from a WSDL file and uses this in a .NET core 3.1 project. I can't set the Authorization header through `ClientCredentials` and a `BasicHttp(s)Binding`. I used hookbin to see my request. This is my code:

```cs
BasicHttpsBinding binding= new BasicHttpsBinding();

//for http
//binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;

binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://hookb.in/...");

var soapClient = new RandomServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
soapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
soapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "bla";

soapClient.CallServiceMethod(new Request { Foo = "Bar" });
```

I already tried using other Bindings like `WSHttpBinding` like the Microsoft documentation suggests: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-basic-authentication

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60714907/9124424
I found a solution, but i still wonder why the code in my question does not work

So you need to add an `IClientMessageInspector` and an `IEndpointBehavior`

```cs
    public class AddHttpHeaderMessageEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        private readonly IClientMessageInspector _httpHeaderMessageInspector;

        public AddHttpHeaderMessageEndpointBehavior(Dictionary<string, string> headers)
        {
            _httpHeaderMessageInspector = new HttpHeaderMessageInspector(headers);
        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {

        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(_httpHeaderMessageInspector);
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {

        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {

        }
    }
    
    public class HttpHeaderMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _headers;

        public HttpHeaderMessageInspector(Dictionary<string, string> headers)
        {
            _headers = headers;
        }

        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {

        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            if (request.Properties.Count == 0 || request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] == null)
            {
                request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, new HttpRequestMessageProperty());
            }
            var headersCollection = ((HttpRequestMessageProperty)request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name]).Headers;

            foreach (var header in _headers) headersCollection[header.Key] = header.Value;

            return null;
        }
    }
```

And then you can add this `IEndpointBehavior` to the `Endpoint` in the client instance

```cs
BasicHttpsBinding binding= new BasicHttpsBinding();

//for http
//binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;

binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://hookb.in/...");

var soapClient = new RandomServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"Authorization", $"Basic --INSERT TOKEN--"}
                }));
var behavior = new AddHttpHeaderMessageEndpointBehavior(headers);
soapClient.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(behavior);
soapClient.CallServiceMethod(new Request { Foo = "Bar" });
```

Answer (score 1):

For me Stutje's solution works perfect, except:

- needed to remove `binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;`, otherwise it asking to set credentials directly.
- set `binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;` to use https