# Consume WCF service using a web reference and add a custin header in the request (C#,.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to call a service from a wsdl imported [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMv7t.png)

Here is an example of the code and I don't know how/where I have to pass the securityToken as header.

```
ProjectName.Service.ServiceClient serviceClient = new ProjectName.Service.ServiceClient();
int result = serviceClient.getDataFromDS(inputDTO); // <- Here i got the error because it doesn't find the SecurityToken in the header.
```

from Postman the call(POST) works, because I can put the header here:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEZSa.png)

It also works using the (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest but I have to use the import wsdl as a client service.
Here is an example of working call:

```
ProjectName.Service.LoginServiceClient loginServiceClient = new ProjectName.Service.LoginServiceClient();
loginServiceClient.login(loginDTO);
```

But here is so easy because it accepts only a xml input(inputDTO) and not a value in the header.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a custom HTTP header to every WCF call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-http-header-to-every-wcf-call)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to pass values to the header, usually use [IDispatchMessageInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) on the server-side, and use [IClientMessageInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) on the client-side.

It might look something like this:

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
{
    HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestMessage;
    object httpRequestMessageObject;
    if (request.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, out httpRequestMessageObject))
    {
        httpRequestMessage = httpRequestMessageObject as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpRequestMessage.Headers[USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER]))
        {
            httpRequestMessage.Headers[USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER] = this.m_userAgent;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER, this.m_userAgent);
        request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestMessage);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Hope it helps.