# WCF Set Headers Programmatically

Tags: wcf, .net-core

All time I invoke wcf service I need to set headers programmatically,
in my example I have to set all nodes of identity node (Identity, AppName, AppKey, UserId, IdentityProvider)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://.../services">
   <soapenv:Header>
<Identity xmlns="http://.../">
<AppName>test1</AppName>
<AppKey>test2</AppKey>
<UserId>test3</UserId>
<IdentityProvider>test4</IdentityProvider>
</Identity>
</soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
```

I've read this post [How to add a custom HTTP header to every WCF call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-http-header-to-every-wcf-call) but it seems to be incomplete and I'm looking for full example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below

```
 public class UserInf
 {
     public string AppName { get; set; }
     public string AppKey { get; set; }
     public string UserId { get; set; }
     public string IdentityProvider { get; set; }

 }


UserInf credentials = new UserInf();

 credentials.AppName = "Test1";
 credentials.AppKey = "Test2";
 credentials.UserId = "Test3";
 credentials.IdentityProvider = "Test4";
 MessageHeader myHeader0 = MessageHeader.CreateHeader(
        "Identity", "http:asd.com", credentials);

 OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(myHeader0);
```

If it is a response object, it is added in the interface code of WCF:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)

{
    UserInf credentials = new UserInf();

 credentials.AppName = "Test1";
 credentials.AppKey = "Test2";
 credentials.UserId = "Test3";
 credentials.IdentityProvider = "Test4";
 MessageHeader myHeader0 = MessageHeader.CreateHeader(
        "Identity", "http:asd.com", credentials);

 OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(myHeader0);

    return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
}
```

[image]

If it is a request object, add the following code to the client call:

```
WS.ServiceClient myclient = new WS.ServiceClient();

 
using (OperationContextScope scope=new OperationContextScope(myclient.InnerChannel))
        {
         UserInf credentials = new UserInf();

 credentials.AppName = "Test1";
 credentials.AppKey = "Test2";
 credentials.UserId = "Test3";
 credentials.IdentityProvider = "Test4";
 MessageHeader myHeader0 = MessageHeader.CreateHeader(
        "Identity", "http:asd.com", credentials);

 OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(myHeader0);
    myclient.GetData(1); 
    }
```

As for how to delete the namespace inside, I took a look at its properties that are read-only.

[image]

You can modify the code to try to delete the namespace.

Comment: It cannot work because the Identity node is root element of AppName, AppKey and so on...

Comment: Thank for your replay, however through my implementation you don't need to use OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders for every call towards other service endpoint which require the same headers.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved by implementing the IClientMessageInspector interface thanks to post [How to add a custom HTTP header to every WCF call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-http-header-to-every-wcf-call) by applying some other things like following:

```
// IClientMessageInspector  Impl..
 public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
 { 
     request.Headers.Add(new ProcessHeader());

     return null;
 }



public class ProcessGuidHeader : MessageHeader
 {

     private string _name = "Identity";
     private string _elementName = "AppName";
     private string _namespace = "http://...site..com/";


     public override string Name
     {
         get { return _name; }
     }

     public override string Namespace
     {
         get { return _namespace; }
     }

     protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
     {

         XmlReader r1 = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader("<AppName>test</AppName>"));
         r1.MoveToContent();
         writer.WriteNode(r1, false);

         XmlReader r2 = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader("<AppKey>test</AppKey>"));
         r2.MoveToContent();
         writer.WriteNode(r2, false);

         XmlReader r3 = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader("<UserId>test</UserId>"));
         r3.MoveToContent();
         writer.WriteNode(r3, false);

         XmlReader r4 = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader("<IdentityProvider>test</IdentityProvider>"));
         r4.MoveToContent();
         writer.WriteNode(r4, false);
     }
```